# Probability of getting exactly 5 heads in 10 flips of an unfair coin with 0.7 chance of tails

Tags: probability

If a coin has a $0.7$ chance of landing tails. What is the probability of getting EXACTLY $5$ heads in $10$ flips?

I know that the probability is $\frac{63}{256}$ if the coin is fair but I cannot work out how to do this problem. This is all i have so far: 
$$
\frac{(10!)}{2^{10}\cdot 5!\cdot5!} = \frac{252}{1024} = \frac{63}{256}
$$

Comment: Hint: Binomial distribution

Comment: Refer this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Are you looking for *odds* or *probability*? These two values are different.

Comment: @amd meant probability, sorry

Comment: @celtschk Not too sure on what binomial distribution is, but I read the wiki and got an answer in the region of 0.1029. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: @KeyboardLamp: Yes.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways you can arrange five heads and five tails (first toss to last) is $_{10}C_{5}$.

The probability of getting five of each, in *one* particular order (say all tails, then all heads), is $0.3^50.7^5$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

In the numerator: 5 heads, so $$\binom{10}{5}(1-0.7)^5(0.7)^{10-5}$$

Comment: shouldn't i t be 0.3 in stead of the 0.7 in there? because the 0.7 represents the chance of landing a tail

Comment: Yes, $1-0.7=0.3$ is the probability of head. So $5$ times we have heads, and the remaining $10-5=5$ times we have tails. The number of combinations is $\binom{10}{5}$.